# How to post json String in android

Tags: android

How I post json String. My json is correct but problem to post to server.

```
 API = public static String getaddProject= "http://10.10.10.64:10003/API/Project/Add";
```

**Code**

```
     for(int i=0; i<iArr.size(); i++){

    if(i==0){

        st = "{\"userId\":" + iArr.get(i) + "}";
        str += st;
    }else if(i>0 && i<iArr.size()-1){
        st = ",{\"userId\":" + iArr.get(i) + "}";
        str+=st;
    }else if(i==iArr.size()){
        st = ",{\"userId\":" + iArr.get(i) + "}]}";
        str+=st;
    }
}
String myPost = "{\"project\":{\"Name\":"+ "\""+ title + "\""
        + ",\"Description\":" + "\""+ desc + "\""
        + ",\"createdBy\":" + usrid + ""
        + ",\"startDate\":" + "\""+ startdate + "\""
        + ",\"dueDate\":" + "\""+ duedate + "\""
        + ",\"projectLeadId\":" + leadPosition + ""
        + ",\"QAId\":" + QAssurencePosition + ""
        + ",\"TotalHour\":" +"\""+ edtHour + "\""+ "},\"members\":[";
myPost += str;
myPost +="]}";
RequestPackage myPackage = new RequestPackage();
myPackage.setUri(getaddProject);
myPackage.setMethod("POST");
myPackage.setParam("posting", myPost);
new MyTask().execute(myPackage);

Toast.makeText(CreateProject.this,"Testing String: " + myPost,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

Log.d("My Post :",myPost);
 }
```

I get the following result:

```
{"data":null,"statusCode":200,"isSuccess":true,"message":"input data is required"}
```

> message : Input data is required

And some more code from the comments:

```
protected String doInBackground(RequestPackage... params) {
    String content = HttpManager.getData(params[0]);
    //...
}
```

Comment: What problem u are getting?

Comment: please log myPost variable and which network library are you using ?

Comment: why it is not show me... "your project successfully add" in message

Comment: network library ????

Comment: @user5653405: Use JSONObject and JSONArray for creating `myPost ` in

Answer (score -1):

You should use a library for JSON parsing like Gson or Xml Parser.

In your Java Code you can use JSONObject api's as well, and add using typical .put methods.